# Monads, >>=, and "nested lambdas"

Tags: haskell, monads

I think I am stuck after reading [Graham Hutton's monad article](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/monads).
Following is the brick wall. (Text from the article)

> Using `>>=`, our evaluator can now be rewritten as:
>
> ```
> eval (Val n) = Just n
> eval (Div x y) = eval x >>= (\n -> eval y >>= (\m -> safediv n m))
> ```
>
> The case for division can be read as follows: **evaluate x and call
>   its result value n**, then **evaluate y and call its result value m**,
>   and finally combine the two results by applying safediv.

I haven't understood how the **temporary results are stored** from lambdas in `n` and `m`. What are the rules for "nesting of lambdas" and retriving its results?

---

*edit:*

I accept that I am a newbie and my basics are not strong .One reason for bad understanding  was the confusion with definition and result of  bind operator `>>=` . I   over looked the fact that bind operator will return the value of  computation

```
"f applied on x".
```

I'll try to summarize my (half- ) understanding .

Definition of bind operator in this context:

```
(>>=) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
Nothing  >>=  _  = Nothing
(Just x) >>=  f  = f x
```

Interpretation of the above definition:

**Signature** - Bind operator takes type of `Maybe a` ,another higher order function with a signature `((a->maybe a)`  and applies it on `a` and returns a resulting value with type  `Maybe b`

**Pattern 1** - When `Maybe a`  is `Nothing`, bind operator don't care about the function with a signature `(a->maybe a)` --   returns `Nothing` .

**Pattern 2** - When `Maybe a` is `Just x`, bind operator cares about the function and applies the function ie ( `f x` , function `f`  gets applied with value `x` from `Just x` ) and returns the resulting value  with a type `Maybe b`.

Here `a` and `b` can be of different types .For example `a` can be an integer `b` can be a `String` .

Now if we apply our definition of bind in the given division example,

```
eval (Val n)   = Just n
eval (Div x y) = eval x >>= (\n ->
                  eval y >>= (\m ->
                  safediv n m))
```

`eval x`   in  the line `eval (Div x y)`   **will return `Just n`**  based on the pattern  **`eval (Val n) = Just n`** . This is the first parameter for the bind operator . hence we can re write  it as

```
eval (Div x y) = Maybe a >>= f   -- .We are applying `>>=` operator.

eval (Div x y) = Just n  >>= (\n -> eval y >>= (\m -> safediv n m))
```

Because the result  of bind operator  `>>=`  is **`f x`**  in our context,  the "lambda"  **`(\n -> eval y >>= (\m -> safediv n m))`**  will be applied on `n` .

Could you please let me know whether my understanding till this point is correct.
If this understanding is correct  ,I need to figure out the result of application of "lambda"  **`(\n -> eval y >>= (\m -> safediv n m))`** on **`n`**:

```
 (\n -> eval y >>= (\m -> safediv n m)) n
```

Comment: Please don't try to learn about monads of any sort until you are *thoroughly* comfortable with lambda forms. Until then, you should stick to defining pure functions and evaluating expressions in GHCi. It may take you a few days or weeks before you're ready to move on to fancy things like using monads to structure interpreters. That's really okay.

Comment: *" `eval x` in the line `eval (Div x y)` will return `Just n` based on the pattern `eval (Val n) = Just n`"* -- ***if*** `x` itself is`Val n`. But it could also be another `Div p q` expression with some other  subexpressions `p`, `q`.

Comment: *"Because the result of bind operator  `>>=` is `f x` in our context, the "lambda"  `(\n -> eval y >>= (\m -> safediv n m))` will be applied on `n`"*. Yes. But to be more precise, if `(eval x)` has produced `Just k`, then the "lambda" will be applied on `k`: `(\n -> eval y >>= (\m -> safediv n m)) k`. Because `(Just k) >>= f = f k`.

Comment: Thanks every one . I wrote a simple lambda expression and compared it . eg:     (\x->(\y-> (x `div` y) )4    )400       .  Here 400 is in the place of n in the monad example and 4 is in the place of m .

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid If you don't understand the basics of lexical scoping and lexical closures, then you'll have a hard time understanding such "state" management in nested lambdas, especially in the case of desugared monad code.

So the answer to your question lies really not in what you're asking but some missing prerequisites in your understanding.

Consider

```hs
> let f = \x -> \y -> y * 2 + x * 7
> let f' = f 3
```

now `f'` contains kind of like a closure — it's the body of the first lambda where the value of `x` has been remembered as `3`. Passing a value to `f'` in turn, also "fills in the placeholder" `y, after which the remembered value of x and the now available value of y are (upon demand) used to evaluate the expression 2y+7x.

```hs
> f' 4
29
```

Monads simply use such constructions for remembering values from previous monadic steps. Of course typically you use the `do` syntactic sugar which hides away such lambda plumbing.

---

P.S. In case it might not be obvious, these two lines are equivalent:

```hs
> let f = \x -> \y -> y * 2 + x * 7
> let f x y = y * 2 + x * 7
```

I simply used the explicitly [curried](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) form to draw a parallel to the monadic lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure I understand your question. The "temporary result" of `eval x` for example becomes `n`, and the "temporary result" of `eval y` becomes `m`. For `safediv n m`, both `n` and `m` are accessible in the scope, so you can refer to them, just as you can refer to any variables in any scope you are in, e.g. when you nest `let` expressions.

Note that the value (e.g. `n`) is "handed" to the lambda `(\n -> ...)` by way of the bind (`>>=`) definition for `Maybe`, i.e. `(>>=) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b`. So for example `expr x` evaluates to a `Maybe a` which you then apply to `>>=`, e.g. `themaybe >>= lambda`. In the definition below, the lambda corresponds to `f`, so you can see that if the `eval x` evaluated to a `Just a`, it'll apply the `x` to the lambda (i.e. `f x`). The lambda itself evaluates to a `Maybe a`, which is why you can further chain/nest another `>>= lambda`.

```
 (>>=)   :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
 m >>= f =  case m of
               Nothing -> Nothing
               Just x  -> f x
```